# Can I transfer my answer on a duplicate question to the duplicate target?

Tags: feature-request, status-bydesign, closing, answers

I [answered a question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/121025/23), and later on that question was marked as a duplicate. After checking out the original question closer I realized that my answer to the dupe answers the original question better (in my opinion) than the existing answers.

Can I transfer my answer to the original?

Comment: *[status-bydesign]* - As MatthewRead mentioned, mods can 'merge' questions which (among other things) will transfer answers across, but this is generally a big step - not taken often and used in exceptional circumstances. It's easier to delete and re-create your answer on the new question as covered by murgatroid99 and badp.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you have an answer that you think is better than existing answers for a question, you should post it. If you are worried that you will be creating duplicate content, you can just delete the answer to the closed question. There is no build in mechanism for transferring answers, but you can just copy the markdown source of the answer into an answer to the other question.

Comment: Merging (moderator-only) transfers answers, but is not generally used for that purpose alone.

Answer (score 4):

Simply copy paste your answer on the original question.